# Update values using lapply in a data.table conditional to nrow

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I want to update the values of a column in a data.table conditional to two other columns in the same table.

This code here works in a way, but I wanted to update the values in my DT instead of returning a list of DTs.

## reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools)

# Create Data Table
  DT <- as.data.table(combinations(3,2,1:3,repeats=TRUE))
  DT[, V3 := 9999 ]

DT
>   V1 V2   V3
>1:  1  1 9999
>2:  1  2 9999
>3:  1  3 9999
>4:  2  2 9999
>5:  2  3 9999
>6:  3  3 9999
```

## My code:

```
# create function

stationary <- function(i) {DT[i, V3 := if (V1==V2) 0  else  V1+V2 ]}

i <- 1:nrow(DT)

DT <- lapply(i, stationary)  # This returns a list of identical data tables
```

## The result I wanted:

```
DT
>   V1 V2 V3
>1:  1  1  0
>2:  1  2  3
>3:  1  3  4
>4:  2  2  0
>5:  2  3  5
>6:  3  3  0
```

Comment: Iterating over all observations is always slow. You could at least use `ifelse`.

Comment: I was initially considering a loop with `if else` . I'm still getting my head around the best approach to my problem. I might have to post another question.

Comment: I wrote `ifelse`, which is a vectorized function, and not `if else`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this:

```
DT[, V3 := (V1 + V2) * (V1 != V2)]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  1  1  0
#2:  1  2  3
#3:  1  3  4
#4:  2  2  0
#5:  2  3  5
#6:  3  3  0
```

It's fast and simple.

Comment: I think you were ripped off there. Though my guess is that your solution is too complicated for the OP to understand. For example, they probably don't understand that `(V1 != V2)` becomes a binary vector while multiplied by `(V1 + V2)`. Maybe worth adding explanations for future beginner readers.

Comment: I'm not sure that I was ripped off. @jangorecki's solution might avoid the vector scan and use binary search and thus might be faster.

Comment: binary search on what? He didn't key by any column and when running `==` on and unkeyed data.table it is actually will be slower because it will try to set a secondary key first. But in this case he is comparing two different variables each time instead of a variable versus a value, how will the data be keyed in such situation? Maybe by `V1`? Still the first run shouldn't be faster AFAIK. Either-way, I think the speed trade will be minor compared to way over-complicated code IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chaining:

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools) # combinations()
DT <- as.data.table(combinations(3,2,1:3,repeats=TRUE))
DT[, V3 := 9999 ]
DT[V1==V2, V3 := 0
   ][V1!=V2, V3 := as.numeric(V1+V2)
     ][]
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  1  1  0
# 2:  1  2  3
# 3:  1  3  4
# 4:  2  2  0
# 5:  2  3  5
# 6:  3  3  0
```

You can avoid `as.numeric` call if you stick with integers, so `V3 := 9999L` and `V3 := 0L`.

Comment: Hmm,,, that looks very unnecessarily complicated, while calling numeral `[.data.table` (chaining) and filters.... I would call this a `dplyr` answer under a `data.table` disguise.

Comment: I agree but it is much easier to extend this solution to more complicated cases.